# Receiving "Deployment Role Instances Not In Started State After 30 seconds" Azure PHP

Tags: php, deployment, azure

I keep receiving this message when trying to deploy a test php application into my Azure Emulator

> ```
> Using session id 1
> Warning : Remapping public port 80 to 81 to avoid conflict during emulation.
> Warning : Remapping private port 80 to 82 in role 'PhpOnAzure.Web' to avoid conf
> lict during emulation.
> Created: deployment16(6)
> Deployment role instances not in "Started" state after 30 seconds.
> Exported interface at http://127.0.0.1:81/.
> C:\temp\WindowsAzurePHPApp\build/WindowsAzurePHPApp.cspkg
> C:\Users\Manu>
> ```

I followed some troubleshooting off the "Building and deploying a PHP Application on Azure" tutorial (Checked CGI, also activated PHP) and didn't anywhere. Anyone else come across the same problem? My output from this code is a blank page in firefox that says connection timed out.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have any other web server software running, such as Apache? IIS need control in order to function properly. The connection issue in Firefox makes me think maybe IIS is being blocked or not starting. Another possibility to look for, sometimes IIS gets confused with PHP and adds two of them to the list of modules. Check that as well